# Detecting UITextField changes without triggering another in a related field

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following to detect if the user makes a change to the contents of a field:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    field1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
    field2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
}
```

and

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // if user changed field1, calculate f2 = 2 * f1 and put result in field2
    // else if user changed field2, calculate f1 = f1 / 2  and put result in field1
}
```

When the user changes the contents field1 the result written to field2 triggers the textfieldDidChange again - which I clearly do not want to happen.

Is there a way to detect HOW the change to the UITextField was made, i.e., user entry vs programmatically?  Or a method that only detects user changes?  Or do I have to build it myself?

Comment: Are you really sure that setting the `text` property via code is really triggering the target selector? Such events should only be called when a user makes the change to avoid cases just like this.

Comment: I agree; I just tested your code and changing field2 programatically doesn't call the action handler

Comment: Interesting...  Something else must be going on, and I am having trouble pinning it down.  But that taught me something new!  Thank you!